# ssh: Could not resolve hostname sama5d27-som1-ek-sd:

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, remote-server

I am trying to set up remote connection between my Desktop machine ( Windows machine ) and remote machine ( Linux machine ).

For that, I am following the steps described here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/set-up-fips-compliant-secure-remote-linux-development?view=vs-2019#to-create-and-use-an-rsa-key-file

But, in step 2, when I try, From Windows, to copy the public key to the Linux machine using this command :

```
scp C:\Users\wiemz/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@sama5d27-som1-ek-sd:
```

This error occurs :

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname sama5d27-som1-ek-sd: H\364te Unknown.
>   lost connection

I verfied my Linux internet connection with ping command and it's going well. Besides, when I typed this command on the Linux machine :

```
ssh root@sama5d27-som1-ek-sd
```

it says :

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname sama5d27-som1-ek-sd: Temporary failure
>   in name resolution

How can I fix this problem please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your OS can't resolve the hostname you use. You should provide FQDN like `web.example.com` or IP address of the machine. For example

```
scp file root@IP:
```

or

```
scp file root@web.example.com:
```

Comment: So I must replace `scp C:\Users\wiemz/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@sama5d27-som1-ek-sd:` with `scp C:\Users\wiemz/.ssh/id_rsa.pub IP_HOST_MACHINE` ?

Comment: When I try `scp file root@IP:` it tells me : `ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
lost connection`

Comment: @Gonn, you should add the IP of the host you want to access, not your IP/hostname

Comment: This is the commnd I used `scp C:\Users\wiemz/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@127.0.0.1:`

Comment: @Gonn, this will contact your local machine. Use IP of the remote machine where you want to send the file

Comment: Yes I am using the IP of the remote machine which is 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Gonn, again, Use IP of the remote machine where you want to send the file!

Comment: I really did not get what do you mean! When I type `ifconfig` in Windows command prompt ( where the file desired to be coppied ) I get this IP adress : `192.168.1.1` and when I tape `ifconfig` from Linux ( where I want to copy the file to ) it's `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207973/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-gonn).